# Add Attribute Bulk Value Using CSV File in Magento 2.3.3?

Tags: product, magento2.3, attributes, product-attribute, csv

I have Magento 2.3.3 Store And I have too many Product Dropdown Attribute And One Attribute have a something 500 1000 value.

So How can I add multiple values using CSV file or other options so, please give me an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Do some customization for that.